# Problem rendering animation with Eevee blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

I recently rendered an animation of a car driving on a road. I haven't had any problems before but with this animation it flickers, specially the car and the trees. I Rendered with Eevee.

If you guys know any solutions please help.

Take a look at the animation here:
[Car Driving Animation Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1N7YSgJanA)

Comment: Hey, question: If you select your camera, what are the values at "Clip start" and "End"?

Comment: Try using Cycles engine.

Comment: @DarkSoul Turns out the Clip Start was very low. I played with the Clip Start and End and the result is much better! Thanks!